# ClassCastExpection in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create `ViewPager` with dynamically adding tabs to `ActionBar`, but I am getting `ClassCastExpection`.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    android.app.ActionBar actionBar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Tabacti mAdapter;
    private String[] tabs = {"Learn", "Quiz"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new Tabacti(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(android.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Learn").setTabListener(this));
    /*for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener((android.app.ActionBar.TabListener) this));
    }*/
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: show the logcat output as well

Comment: add your `import` statements as well, i think the problem is that you use `support library v4` somewhere, and you dont somewhere else

Comment: MBH yes thanks actually this was the problem i used support library v4 at some classes where as didnt use them in one class. thanks a lot.